# Getting HttpHostConnection Exception

Tags: android

I am using eclipse and my android phone via usb to run my app . My api rest is made in php and use xampp and it run on port 8080 http://localhost:8080.
but i am getting HttpHost Conncetion Exception.

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

                String username = ed_user.getText().toString();
                String address = ed_add.getText().toString();
                String age = ed_age.getText().toString();
                String contact = ed_cnt.getText().toString();
                String email = ed_email.getText().toString();
                String gender = ed_gender.getText().toString();
                String password = ed_password.getText().toString();



                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpRequest = new HttpPost(

                "http://192.168.56.1:8080/Project/reg.php");


                 httpRequest.setHeader( "Content-Type", "application/json" );        

                 JSONObject json = new JSONObject();     

                 json.put("username", username);
                 json.put("address", address);
                 json.put("contact", contact);
                 json.put("age", age);
                 json.put("email", email);
                 json.put("gender", gender);
                 json.put("password", password);


                 Log.i("JSON Object", json.toString());
                 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());

                 se.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
                 se.setContentType("application/json");

                 httpRequest.setEntity(se);
                 HttpResponse httpRes = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

                 java.io.InputStream inputStream = httpRes.getEntity()
                            .getContent();
                    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                            inputStream);
                    BufferedReader brReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    strServerResponse = stringBuilder.toString().trim();
                    Log.e("strServerResponse", ""+strServerResponse.toString());

                    if (brReader != null) {
                        strServerResponse = brReader.readLine().toString();
                    }
                    if (strServerResponse != null) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strServerResponse);
                            String DataStatus = jsonObj.getString("status");

                            System.out.println(DataStatus);
                            if (DataStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("SUCCESS")) {

                                JSONObject mainDataObject = jsonObj 
                                        .getJSONObject("data");


                                String u_name = mainDataObject.optString("u_name");
                                String u_contact = mainDataObject.optString("u_contact");
                                String u_address = mainDataObject.optString("u_address");
                                String u_age = mainDataObject.optString("u_age");
                                String u_gender = mainDataObject.optString("u_gender");
                                String u_email = mainDataObject.optString("u_email");
                                String u_password = mainDataObject.optString("u_email");



                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                                editor.putString("u_name", u_name);
                                editor.putString("u_contact",u_contact);                             
                                editor.putString("u_address", u_address);
                                editor.putString("u_age", u_age);
                                editor.putString("u_gender", u_gender);
                                editor.putString("u_email", u_email);
                                editor.putString("u_password", u_password);


                                editor.commit();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                            finally{

                            }

                        } else {
                            JSONObject mainDataObject = jsonObj 
                                    .getJSONObject("error");

                            String client_id = mainDataObject.optString("error_code");

                            error_id=Integer.parseInt(client_id);


                            System.out.print(client_id);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

     catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;

}
```

i have tried using my IP address instead of localhost but still not working

Comment: Can you put your logcat here.

Comment: Instead of `localhost`, use your machine IP, for example `http://12.123.123.123:8080/`

Answer (score 1):

Your phone and the pc should be in the same network. To do so, you can do anyone of the following things:

1. Connect both of them to a common WiFi and use the IP address given by the WiFi router to your PC in the application code.
2. If a common WiFi is not available, connect your PC to the hotspot of your phone. Than use the IP address given by the phone hotspot to your PC in the application code.
3. If any of the above options are not possible, use an emulator on the PC where your API resides. You can connect to your API by using the IP address `10.0.2.2` with the emulator . So your URL would be `http://10.0.2.2:8080/Project/reg.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your device connected in the same wifi network?

**Easiest way to check the url from your phone is:**

Go to the device browser and try to browse your URL. If it doesn't work in browser then it will not work in your app.